# QT: Can't deploy JPEG capability onto fresh windows machine

Tags: qt

Jpegs are fine on my developer machine, but are not supported when i deploy my application to a fresh machine. all jpeg files used in stylesheets are still built with the application's resources, but are never displayed.

1. I tried deploying an "imageformats" folder, child of the executable folder, containing a "qjpeg4.dll" inside.
2. I tried linking against the qjpeg4.lib in my .pro file, WITH what's specified above.

still no good. Is there something in code I need to specify?

Comment: The "imageformats" folder should be a *child* of your executable's folder. Was that just a typo?

Comment: Yes. it's a child of the exe's folder and a sibling of the executable file (*.exe). Still no good.

Comment: Your setup, as you describe it, is exactly what I have. It should work. Maybe you are building a debug version of your app so it is looking for `qjpeg4d.dll`, or you accidentally deployed the debug plugin dll?

Comment: I copied both versions of the jpeg.dll, debug and non debug. still no good. something else is wrong. Are you sure this is the ONLY step required? just having a "imageformats" folder with those DLLs in your app's folder?

Comment: Unbelievable: It doesn't work because i ran on a virtual machine, windows 7 using VMWare Fusion. On a normal box it DOES run with the jpeg plug in. That's very strange. Why won't this work on a virtual machine? i mean, it's a simple file/folder path thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a guess, but I'm wondering if there is some dependency of the plugin that cannot be resolved on the virtual machine. Like you said, it is a simple file/folder thing, so it is probably finding the plugin dll. But maybe the dll is failing to load because it cannot resolve one if its dependencies.

The most likely culprit would be the C++ runtimes. Are you deploying those side-by-side in the application directory, or installed via the redistributable? If the former, the plugin may not be able to find them since it is in a different directory. To track this down, you could use the "Dependency Walker" and "SxSTrace.exe" tools.

Comment: It's interesting. I do have the "Microsoft.VC80.CRT" folder in the executable folder. I also have the "imageformats" folder there with the jpeg DLLs. The interesting thing is, if I copy the same "Microsoft.VC80.CRT" into the "imageformats" folder, it works well, on the virtual machine. but if I just look for "Visual Studio 2005 redistributables" and install it on the virtual machine, it won't work just by itself. as if the "Microsoft.VC80.CRT" has different content from what you can download rom Microsoft. Very strange.

Comment: Ok, then you misunderstood deploying for windows. You need to install msvc redistributables on your testing machine to make it work properly. You SHOULDN'T copy MSVC redist withing your app "just like that"

Comment: @RM1970 - Yeah, the WinSxS logic can be very confusing. There are *many* pitfalls with the C++ runtimes. For an overview, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235342(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to deploy qt plugins with your application. [Deploying Qt apps on Windows](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-windows.html#application-dependencies)